# I have problem when I make Apple ID using iTunes

Tags: itunes, apple-id, password

I have problem when I make an Apple ID using iTunes.

The email with a code arrives, but I can not create the id.
[image]

What are the password complexity rules to get past this error?

Answer (score 4):

Basically Apple is saying you need to choose a more complex password.

Currently, your Apple ID password **must** have eight or more characters and include upper and lowercase letters, and at least one number. Apple also uses other password rules to make sure your password isn't easy to guess (things like your name, common words, sequential numbers, etc can be rejected). See [Security and your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT201303) for more information.

I use a password manager (1Password, there are others) that will generate VERY complex passwords, like this:

1xwEFO6^))hub%$s1

and all you have to do is unlock it and it generates the password and remembers it for you. So you only have to remember ONE password, the one that unlocks it. Other password managers work the same way.

So you will need to create a more complex password before Apple will let you create an account with them. And there is no way around this.

So my recommendation? Make a more complex password and get a password manager to help you remember the one's you create.